# Import existing order data to mailchimp

Tags: php, woocommerce, mailchimp

I've read multiple times that you can send e-commerce data to mailchimp with an API code. However, I have no clue how this works.

How would I send something to mailchimp?

I found something about `ecommOrderAdd(string apikey, array order)`
(https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/ecommorderadd.func.php)

This supposed to be used for sending data I think?

Comment: You are looking to something like that this cheapest commercial plugin does: [WooChimp - WooCommerce MailChimp Integration](http://codecanyon.net/item/woochimp-woocommerce-mailchimp-integration/6044286) or this cheap one to [MailChimp for WordPress Premium (eCommerce360)](https://mc4wp.com/features/)

Comment: I am actually working with this plugin already but this plugin only supports the import of new order data and not old data.